# About automating OAuth for YoutubeDataAPIv3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, youtube

When I use GCP's YoutubeDataAPIv3 to obtain video information for my channel, I use OAuth authentication, but if I implement it via run_local_server(), the authentication process will require human intervention, but I don't know how to automate it. Do you have it?

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.9
$ pip list | grep google
google-api-core           2.14.0
google-api-python-client  2.107.0
google-auth               2.23.4
google-auth-httplib2      0.1.1
google-auth-oauthlib      1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos  1.61.0
```

It would be helpful if you could give me some reference examples.

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth-oauthlib/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html

Comment: It is not possible to automate Google authentication for users. The user must interact with a web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John
I guess so!